# How to create jquery zoom and fade in effect?

Tags: jquery, animation, zooming

Can anyone explain logically how this site works, specifically with opening one of the images? I just want to understand how something like this is created without flash:http://www.laurab.net/

I haven't seen a jquery plugin that can allow for this type of animation. Is it flash? Is it custom javascript?

Comment: The best way to learn it is to check the website's source code using developer tools and learn from it.
The designer used jQuery, jQuery's libraries and HTML5 canvas.

Answer (score 0):

https://github.com/heartcode/CanvasLoader

That is what is uses infact i think its pretty cool

http://www.backbonetechnology.com/blog/html5-css3/heartcode-canvas-loader-creator

Interestingly its HTML 5 CSS 3

Comment: I was actually thinking of the images, how they open and then return back to the main menu of the page.